# Drawing few graphs with "chart" VS C#

Tags: c#, graph, colors, charts, series

friends! I want to ask you another easy question - how to draw another graph in chart.series? That's what I have:

```
chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
...
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
```

So, I want to draw another one and I trying to use this:

```
chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Red;
...
chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(a, b);
```

But it's error with index, so I can guess that I should to add new series for new graph, right? Hope, you can help me with it!!!

Comment: Oh, ok! I add new series in properties! Is it right?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new serie and then add it to your chart.

```
Series series1 = new Series("series1");
chart1.Series.Add(series1);
```

You can also create them in your .aspx.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" ImageType="Png">
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="Legends1"></asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series0"></asp:Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series2"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
    </asp:Chart>
</form>
```